# NSURLSession Redirection Error

Tags: objective-c, redirect, networking, nsurlsession

So I have NSURLSession setup to follow redirects if it is presented with one. The delegate catches the redirect, then creates a NSURLSessionDataTask using dataTaskWithRequest and the redirect from the willPerformHTTPRedirection as its argument. It works great for everything on my network except the router which does this strange thing (see log below):

```
- [NSURLSession] willPerformHTTPRedirection: <NSURLRequest: 0x60000000d500> { URL: http://192.168.1.1:80:8000/, Method GET, Headers {
Accept =     (
    "*/*"
);
"Accept-Encoding" =     (
    "gzip, deflate"
);
"Accept-Language" =     (
    "en-us"
);
} }
- [NSURLSession] willPerformHTTPRedirection: <NSURLRequest: 0x60000000d540> { URL: http://192.168.1.1:80:8000:8000/, Method GET, Headers {
Accept =     (
    "*/*"
);
"Accept-Encoding" =     (
    "gzip, deflate"
);
"Accept-Language" =     (
    "en-us"
);
} }
-[NSURLSession] willPerformHTTPRedirection: <NSURLRequest: 0x60000000d6b0> { URL: http://192.168.1.1:80:8000:8000:8000/, Method GET, Headers {
Accept =     (
    "*/*"
);
"Accept-Encoding" =     (
    "gzip, deflate"
);
"Accept-Language" =     (
    "en-us"
);
} }
```

Basically it keeps appending the redirect port onto the end of the address. No idea why it is doing this. Every other address (30+ of them) work exactly as expected and follow all redirects to the end. I am going to set a maximum redirect of 10 or so, but this still shouldn't be happening. Anyone have any idea what could cause this?

Here are some results from curl. ...1.115 works fine, while ...1.1 does not. Per the curl results, the main difference I notice is that the Location on 115 drops the port and adds the redirect after, while 1.1 changes the port. I attempted to connect to ...1.1 without any port and the redirects worked correctly, but unfortunately my code requires a port to be part of the string.

[image: Results from curl]

[image]

[image]

```
Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1007 "too many HTTP redirects" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x604000c4bcd0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1007 "(null)"}, NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=http://192.168.1.1:80:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=http://192.168.1.1:80:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000:8000/, NSLocalizedDescription=too many HTTP redirects}
```

Comment: Post the code where you're handling the redirection.  This looks like a bug in that method.

Comment: @dgatwood I added the code. I am using the default completion handler for this method. Works fine for every other device.

Comment: Okay, now let me see the code where you add the port number.

Comment: @dgatwood added the code. Basically pass 3 args, the http type as NSString, host as NSString, and port as an int.

Comment: That's what I figured.  I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are, you're getting a URL that already has a port number and adding a second one.  Either that or some custom script on your web server is doing so.

In your code snippet, instead of adding the port the way you're doing it, construct the URL without it, then do this:

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents componentsWithURL:HOST_URL];
components.port = 80; // or whatever
HOST_URL = [components URL];
```

If that doesn't fix the problem, then it is probably happening in a script on your server/router, and there might not be anything you can do about it, depending.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Definitely a more clean way to assign the port than what I was doing. Unfortunately, even using this method, the same error occurs. Eventually fails due to too many HTTP redirects. Added the error to the original question.

Comment: Per the curl results from the device, the location seems like it is working correctly. So I am not sure if it is the device that is causing the problem, but more likely something wrong with the library?

Comment: Maybe NSURL really doesn't like having the default port specified in the URL.  Why are you including the port number, BTW?  That's a pretty unusual thing to do.